# xcode shows same height for 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I test my app in 3.5 inch and 4 inch. While I `NSLog(@"%@", self.view.frame.size.height);` both 3.5 inch and 4 inch shows height **568**. Now currently I m using xcode 5.. Any can please explain why this shows like that..

Comment: I think you are using self.view.frame.size.height in this condition app using your original view means your xib's height and may be your xib is 4 inch.

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda: Yes un xib it shows 568 but I need to make support in 3.5 inch also bro

Comment: @user2922837 then you have to setFrame as per condition shown in my answer or you have to set object property from xib's show size inspector from right side panel.

Comment: It also depends on when you look at the height. You need to check the height AFTER it's been sized to the current environment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are using self.view.frame.size.height . In this condition app using your original view means your xib's height and may be your xib is 4 inch.

If you want to check UIDevice height than use this condition

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height<568)
{
     NSLog(@"3.5 inch screen");
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"4.0 inch screen");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have two launch images-
one Default.png (for 3.5 inch) and another Default-568h.png (for 4 inch) in your app.
Please check it.

Comment: this just can let your 3.5inch app to fullscreen in 4.0inch.doesn't work for this problem

Comment: Ya know…  so many people on SO need sit their egos DOWN!! THIS IS A HUGE PROBLEM WITH APPLE!!  They will ABSOLUTELY lock your app into thinking it's running as a 3.5 inch display (regardless of size) if you don't have the Default-568h.png in correctly!! I'm sure MANY people have this problem. BUT, sure, lets all bash this guy for giving some good information out!

Comment: Hey , this actually solved it ,  all my view controllers were Inferred but only after adding the images , they got the correct values!

Comment: This worked...have been trying to work this out for a while...thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is returning because your xib size is Retina 4-inch Full Screen. So thats why. So if you really want to it then change it in your xib file either **freeform** or **None**.

Please try to see like this...Definataly it will print according to your screen.

```
NSLog(@"%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height);
```